# Table sorting using pure jquery with asc and desc?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How to do the table sorting using pure jquery with asc and desc for numeric and string. I tried with below code as followed. Here it is working for desc order in numeric values, then i clicked again it is not working displayed as like desc order only not in asc order..
can any one help..

```
<table class="table table-hover" style="width:96%;margin:2%;margin-top:0%" id="patientTable">
    <thead id="theader">
        <tr style="background-color: #5bc0de/*rgb(255, 106, 106)*/;color: #F6F4F4;font-size:12.999999px">
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Pati</th>
            <th>Device Status</th>
            <th>Monitoring Status</th>
            <th>Monitoring Mode</th>
            <th>Service Start</th>
            <th>Service End</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>agesh1</td>
            <td>4535324</td>
            <td>With Patient, Inactive</td>
            <td>Service Ended</td>
            <td>HOLTER</td>
            <td>24 Dec , 2014</td>
            <td>26 Dec , 2014</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>ragesh</td>
            <td>2345457</td>
            <td>With Patient, Inactive</td>
            <td>Service Ended</td>
            <td>HOLTER</td>
            <td>24 Dec , 2014</td>
            <td>26 Dec , 2014</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>abcde name</td>
            <td>123423</td>
            <td>With Patient, Inactive</td>
            <td>Service Ended</td>
            <td>HOLTER</td>
            <td>24 Dec , 2014</td>
            <td>26 Dec , 2014</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#patientTable thead th:eq(0)').click(function () {
        sorttable();
    });
});

function sorttable() {
    var $tbody = $('table tbody');
    $tbody.find('tr').sort(function (a, b) {
        var tda = $(a).find('td:eq(0)').text();
        var tdb = $(b).find('td:eq(0)').text();
        return tda > tdb ? 1
            : tda < tdb ? -1
            : 0;
    }).appendTo($tbody);
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/juL035y2/

https://jsfiddle.net/juL035y2/embedded/result/

Comment: Sorry I mean it works like you said in descending order.

Comment: Check the bellow js fiddle for your answer 

http://jsfiddle.net/n8c87azk/

Answer (score 1):

You could do some small changes:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#patientTable thead th').click(function(){
        //Add parameter for remembering order type
        $(this).attr('data-order', ($(this).attr('data-order') === 'desc' ? 'asc':'desc'));
       //Add aditional parameters to keep track column that was clicked
       sorttable(this, $('#patientTable thead th').index(this));
    });
});
function sorttable(header, index){
 var $tbody = $('table tbody');
 var order = $(header).attr('data-order');
 $tbody.find('tr').sort(function (a, b) {
 var tda = $(a).find('td:eq(' + index + ')').text();
 var tdb = $(b).find('td:eq(' + index + ')').text();
     //Order according to order type
     return (order === 'asc' ? (tda > tdb ? 1 : tda < tdb ? -1 : 0) : (tda < tdb ? 1 : tda > tdb ? -1 : 0));
}).appendTo($tbody);
}
```

Look from [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/juL035y2/2/)